# browserHistory undefined (react router v3)

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router

Im struggling with react router since it returns "browserHistory is undefined" when im trying to push it. Here are my routes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UI from './UI.jsx';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import { browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component { 
  render() {
     return (
         <div>
         <Router history={browserHistory}>
           <div>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
             <Route path="/UI" component={UI}/>
           </div>
         </Router>
         </div>
       );
   }
} 
export default App;
```

And here is the document where i use browserHistory.push(); function:

```
login(e) {
       console.log(this.props.browserHistory);
       e.preventDefault();
       var username = this.inputName.value;
       var password = this.inputPassword.value;
       axios.post(
           'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
           {
               user_name: username,
               user_password: password
           }
       ).then((response) => {
           console.log(response.data);
           console.log(response.data.user_name);
           const username = response.data.user_name;
           session = "&token=" + response.data.session;
           if (username === null) {
               this.setState({ loginFail: 'Användarnamnet eller lösenordet är fel' });
               return;
           } else {
               browserHistory.push('/UI');  //The UI is the component, here i'm getting "cannot read property push of undefined".

               this.setState({
                   showUser: `Hej ${response.data.user_name}`,
                   showLogin: !this.state.showLogin,
                   loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn
               });   
           }
       });
   }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are getting that error becouse you don't have the Login component as a route in the `<Router>`

Comment: Like this?  https://puu.sh/w7AHk/093809060d.png

Still getting the same error :'(

Answer (score 0):

You got to either assign it to a varible by saying

`const { browserHistory } = this.props` and then you can do `browserHistory.push('/UI');`

or just go with `this.props.browserHistory.push('/UI')`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) what you have to do is:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/UI');
```